# Rails: Bundler::GemNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm using Rails on Passenger and getting:

```
Could not find multi_json-1.7.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I assume I just need to install multi_json but it was working a few days ago so I'm curious - what's the best way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experienced this exact same problem on OSX 10.8 after making a system update. After running `bundle update`, I was able to get things working normally again.

While `bundle update` worked for me, in my research, I came across citations from other users who allege to have successfully resolved this issue by deleting their `vendor/cache` folder, thereby forcing Bundler to rebuild existing gem installations.

Comment: **Warning**: `bundle update` will find new versions of all the gems of your bundle and this **may break stuff**. A conservative approach is to use `bundle update multi_json`.

Comment: OK, now this is weird. This problem has resurfaced but this solution is no longer working.

Comment: @SnowCrash: there are numerous solutions to this problem, depending on your build, dependencies, and a wide variety of variables. It's likely that a change in your environment has has broken something elsewhere.